# pyspark MinHashLSH Jaccard distance : not calculating the distance for some pairs

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, distance, similarity

I'm trying to calculate Jaccard distance between some products using MinHashLSH pyspark.

The toy data i use is

```
sdf = spark.read.csv('dt.csv',header=True, sep=',', inferSchema=True)
sdf = sdf.withColumn("ticket", sdf["ticket"].cast(StringType()))
sdf.show(60)

ticket|   Brand|value|
+------+--------+-----+
|     0|     YL |    1|
|     1|     YL |    1|
|     2|     YL |    1|
|     3|     YL |    1|
|     7|     YL |    1|
|     3|   Paco |    1|
|     7|   Paco |    1|
|     0|Lacoste |    1|
|     1|Lacoste |    1|
|     2|Lacoste |    1|
|     4|Lacoste |    1|
|     5|Lacoste |    1|
|     6|Lacoste |    1|
|     0|   Dior |    1|
|     4|   Dior |    1|
|     4|   Boss |    1|
|     5|   Boss |    1|
|     6|   Boss |    1|
|     0|Channel |    1|
|     1|Channel |    1|
|     4|Channel |    1|
|     8|   Boss |    1|
|     8|Channel |    1|
+------+--------+-----+
```

So i want to calculate the Jaccard distance between those brands, so i follow the example in the documentation :

```
order_matrix_jaccard_sdf = sdf.groupby('Brand').agg(F.collect_set('ticket'))
order_matrix_jaccard_sdf = order_matrix_jaccard_sdf.withColumnRenamed('collect_set(ticket)', 'ticket')
order_matrix_jaccard_sdf.show()
```

Out put :

```
+--------+------------------+
|   Brand|            ticket|
+--------+------------------+
|Channel |      [1, 8, 4, 0]|
|   Paco |            [3, 7]|
|Lacoste |[1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 0]|
|     YL |   [3, 1, 2, 7, 0]|
|   Boss |      [5, 8, 4, 6]|
|   Dior |            [4, 0]|
+--------+------------------+
```

Then apply the model :

```
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol='ticket', outputCol="features")
model = cv.fit(order_matrix_jaccard_sdf)
result = model.transform(order_matrix_jaccard_sdf)
mh = MinHashLSH(inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes")
model_mh = mh.fit(result)
model_mh.transform(result)
```

Then calculate the Jaccard distance :

```
jaccard_dist = model_mh.approxSimilarityJoin(result.select(['Brand','features']), result.select(['Brand','features']), 2)
jaccard_dist.show(20)

+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|            datasetA|            datasetB|           distCol|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|0.6666666666666667|
|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|0.6666666666666667|
|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|               0.0|
|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|[Channel , (9,[0,...|               0.5|
|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|               0.0|
|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|[Channel , (9,[0,...|0.7142857142857143|
|[Boss , (9,[1,5,6...|[Boss , (9,[1,5,6...|               0.0|
|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|             0.625|
|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|             0.625|
|[Channel , (9,[0,...|[Channel , (9,[0,...|               0.0|
|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|               0.0|
|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|0.8333333333333334|
|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|[Channel , (9,[0,...|0.5714285714285714|
|[Channel , (9,[0,...|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|               0.5|
|[Channel , (9,[0,...|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|0.7142857142857143|
|[YL , (9,[0,2,3,4...|[Dior , (9,[0,1],...|0.8333333333333334|
|[Channel , (9,[0,...|[Lacoste , (9,[0,...|0.5714285714285714|
|[Paco , (9,[3,4],...|[Paco , (9,[3,4],...|               0.0|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

It lacks the pairs with 'Paco', i calculated the distance using pandas and get the same results except the Paco pairs that miss :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wu5G.png)

How to get also the Paco pairs ? and why i didn't get  them ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Sorry,It was me that shows only the first 20, when i collect all i get the result, i will lift this toy example here since there was not